# How to model spatial covariance using Gaussian processes

Tags: gaussian-process, cross-correlation, spatio-temporal

My data set consists of N noisy time series, each belonging to a point on a surface. The dynamics of each time series are correlated, with correlation decreasing with spatial distance.

I hope to model this data set using Gaussian processes, but need some help getting started.

I wish to estimate a stationary (in time and space) covariance function for measurements on this surface, to both de-noise the actual measurements / time series,  as well as possibly predict optimal locations for future measurements.

Is anyone familiar with either a GP library, or at least some other people's work, related to this problem?

Work-arounds that I can think of are:

- trying to solve the problem for each time step (I believe that is called Kriging?) and performing some sort of averaging over multiple such results
- try to warp my measurement points into some sort of regular grid, simply measure the covariance matrix in this warped space, regularize it (the diagonals should probably be constant), and then do my prediction in that warped space.

Either way, the above feels like reinventing the wheel.  I have also considered using "multi-tasking", for combining heterogenous data sources, such as what is described in "https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2561-dependent-gaussian-processes.pdf", but doesn't seem to let me extend to other locations on the surface, since the spatial information is lost.

Comment: It looks like you have thought of some useful approaches. Noel Cressie has a book published by Wiley on spatial processes.  That is one idea that I can offer.

Comment: You could also put everything into a single GP with a time component to the kernel. That is, the covariance between two points is a function of both the spatial distance and the distance in time; the simplest way to do it would be to multiply a spatial kernel by a time kernel.

Comment: @Dougal that is the thing I would like to do :) Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or library where this is feasible? I'm digging into gpstuff for matlab, but their examples don't seem to generalize to 3D input.

Comment: @Kaare gpstuff certainly supports 3d inputs. Just take one of the 2d examples and add a third dimension to your inputs. :)

Comment: @Michael Cressie (with Christopher Wikle) has a more recent book about spatio-temporal processes that one should look at first:  http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002348.html.

Comment: @whuber That is good to know.